# Using python to parse a large set of filenames concatenated from inconsistent object names

Tags: python, parsing

/tldr Looking to parse a large set of filenames that are a concatenation of two names (container + child) for the original two names where nomenclature is inconsistent.  Python library suggestions or any other guidance appreciated.

I am looking for a way to parse strings for information where the nomenclature and formatting of information within those strings will likely be inconsistent to some degree.

Background
Industry: Automation controls

Problem to be solved:
Time series data is exported from an automation system with a single data point being saved to a single .csv file.  (example:  If the controls system were an environmental controls system the point might be the measured temperature of a room taken at 15 minute intervals.)  It is possible to have an environment where there are a few dozen points that export to CSV files or several thousand points that export to CSV files.  The structure that the points are normally stored in is as follows: points are contained within a controller, controllers are integrated under a management system and occasionally management systems could be integrated into another management system.  The resulting structure is a simple hierarchical tree.

The filenames associated with the CSV files are assembled from the path structure of each point as follows:  Directories are created for the management systems (nested if necessary) and under those directories are the CSV files where the filename is a concatenation of the controller name and the point name.

I have written a python script that processes a monthly export of the CSV files (currently about 5500 of them [growing]) into a structured data store and another that assembles spreadsheets for others to review.  Currently, I am using some really ugly regular expressions and even uglier string.find()s with a list of static string values that I have hand entered to parse out control names and point names for each file so that they can be inserted into the structured data store.

Unfortunately, as mentioned above, the nomenclature used in these environments are rarely consistent.  Point names vary widely.  The point referenced above might be known as ROOMTEMP, RM_T, RM-T, ROOM-T, ZN_T, ZNT, RMT or several other possibilities.  This applies to almost any point contained within a controller.  Controller names are also somewhat inconsistent where they may be named for what type of device they are controlling, the geographic location of the device or even an asset number associated with the device.

I would very much like to get out of the business of hand writing regular expressions to parse file names every time a new location is added.  I would like to write code that reads in filenames and looks for patterns across the filenames and then makes a recommendation for parsing the controller and point name out of each filename.  I already have an interface where I can assign controller name and point name to each point object by hand so if there are errors with the parse I can modify the results.  Ideally, the patterns created by the existing objects would influence the suggested names of new files being parsed.

Some examples of filenames are as follows:
UNIT1254_SAT.csv, UNIT1254_RMT.csv, UNIT1254_fil.csv, AHU_5311_CLG_O.csv, QE239-01_DISCH_STPT.csv, HX_E2_CHW_Return.csv, Plant_RM221_CHW_Sys_Enable.csv, TU_E7_Actual Clg Setpoint.csv, 1725_ROOMTEMP.csv, 1725_DA_T.csv, 1725_RA_T.csv

The order will always be consistent where it is a concatenation of controller name and then point name.  There will most likely be a consistent character used to separate controller name from point name (normally an underscore, but occasionally a dash or some other character.)

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get started with parsing these file names?  I’ve thought through a few ideas, but keep shelving them before trying them prior to implementation because I keep finding the potential for performance issues or identifying failure points.  The rest of my code is working pretty much the way I need it to, I just haven’t figured out an efficient or useful way to pull the correct names out of the filename.  Unfortunately, It is not an option to modify the names on the control system side to be consistent.

Comment: Hello. I understood your problem only roughly. I get the impression that you want to separate the control name from the point name present in a filename, without having a prior notion of what can the names be, and moreover without knowing precisely where the delimiter can be in the filename and if there is only one (1 container name) or two (2 container names). However, you write regular expressions, use str.find() and static string values; so you have some information at the beginning. What is this information ? Try to explain more, please.

Comment: There's some similitude between ROOMTEMP, RM-T, RM-T, ROOM-T, RMT; but not with ZN_T and ZNT, apart the T ! There's possibility to detect the similitude between the 5 first ones, but not with the 2 last ones.

Comment: It seems that you know only the filenames, not the hierarchical tree representing the structure of controllers and management systems. Is it right ?

Comment: I have the information now, because I can visually inspect the file names.  It is also safe to assume that -,_, and a blank space can be delimiters.

Comment: There can be an arbitrary number of containers and an arbitrary number of points under each container

Comment: The management systems are handled fairly easily, because directories are created for each one and if there are multiple management systems integrated into another management system then the associated folders are nested appropriately.

Comment: The ROOMTEMP, RMT, etc. are just examples there are those and many more.

Comment: You can't get the names of management systems and names of controllers separately, in addition to complete names, can you ? Otherwise, you wouldn't have your problem. Correct ?

Comment: In the list you gave, are UNIT1254, AHU_5311, Q39-01, HX_E2, Plant_RM221, TU_E7, 1725 container names because they end with numbers ?

Comment: Unfortunately all I receive is the directory structure filled with the CSV files.

Comment: Controllers ending in numbers is fairly common, but not definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the following code will help you, but I hope it'll give you at least some idea.

Considering that a filename as "QE239-01_STPT_1725_ROOMTEMP_DA" can contain following names
 'QE239-01'
 'QE239-01_STPT'
 'QE239-01_STPT_1725'
 'QE239-01_STPT_1725_ROOMTEMP'
 'QE239-01_STPT_1725_ROOMTEMP_DA'
 'STPT'
 'STPT_1725'
 'STPT_1725_ROOMTEMP'
 'STPT_1725_ROOMTEMP_DA'
 '1725'
 '1725_ROOMTEMP'
 '1725_ROOMTEMP_DA'
 'ROOMTEMP'
 'ROOMTEMP_DA'
 'DA'
as being possible elements (container name or point name) of the filename,
I defined the function `treat()` to return this list from the name.

Then the code treats all the filenames to find all the possible elements of filenames.
The function is based on the idea that in the chosen example the element ROOMTEMP can't follow the element STPT because STPT_ROOMTEMP isn't a possible container name in this example string since there is 1725 between these two elements.

And then, with the help of a function in `difflib` module, I try to discriminate elements that may have some similarity, in order to try to detect patterns under which several elements of names can be gathered.

You must play with the value passed as argument to `cutoff` parameter to choose what could be the best to give interesting results for you.

It's far from being good, certainly, but I didn't understood all aspects of your problem.

```
s =\
"""UNIT1254_SAT
UNIT1254_RMT
UNIT1254_fil
AHU_5311_CLG_O
QE239-01_DISCH_STPT,
HX_E2_CHW_Return
Plant_RM221_CHW_Sys_Enable
TU_E7_Actual Clg Setpoint
1725_ROOMTEMP
1725_DA_T
1725_RA_T
UNT147_ROOMTEMP
TRU_EZ_RM_T
HXX_V2_RM-T
RHXX_V2_ROOM-T
SIX8_ZN_T
Plint_RP228_ZNT
SOHO79_EZ_RMT"""

li = s.split('\n')
print(li)
print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ')

import difflib
from pprint import pprint

def treat(name):
    lu = name.split('_')
    W = []
    while lu:
        W.extend('_'.join(lu[0:x]) for x in range(1,len(lu)+1))
        lu.pop(0)
    return W

if 0:
    q = "QE239-01_STPT_1725_ROOMTEMP_DA"
    pprint(treat(q))
    print('==========================================')

WALL = []
for t in li:
    WALL.extend(treat(t))
pprint(WALL)

for x in WALL:
    j = set(difflib.get_close_matches(x, WALL, n=9000000, cutoff=0.7 ))
    if len(j)>1:
        print(j,'\n')
```